# How to pass '\n' into file in linux kernel mode

Tags: android, c, linux, linux-kernel

I write into a file `const char *prefix`

```
vfs_write(filp, prefix, strlen(prefix), &os);
   pos = pos + strlen(prefix);
```

But it has no '\n' at the end. I tried to write

```
vfs_write(filp, '\n', strlen('\n'), &os);
   pos = pos + strlen('\n');
```

or

```
vfs_write(filp, 0xAD, strlen(0xAD), &os);
   pos = pos + strlen(0xAD);
```

or

```
vfs_write(filp, 0xAD, 1, &os);
   pos = pos + 1;
```

but it doesn't work.

How should i do that?

Comment: You should have gotten compiler *warnings* if compiling with `gcc -Wall`  which you always should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline character is not a string, it's a *character*. The function wants a *pointer* to a buffer of bytes (characters) and by providing a character literal you tell the function to use that character as a pointer, so it will read from address `'\n'` (i.e. address 0x0a) which do not contain a valid string.

Instead do e.g. `vfs_write(filp, "\n", 1, &os);`

The string literal `"\n"` is a pointer to an constant array of characters, in other words a pointer to a buffer of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a string "\n" instead of a character '\n'.